# Changing JTable by ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener

so I'm having trouble with my action listener for my JTable.
Java isn't complaining so it's an error on my part.
I'm trying to make a hotel management software.

I'm storing the rooms in a String array:

```
private String[][] rooms;
private String[] columnNames = { "Room Number" };

JTable results = new JTable(rooms, columnNames);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(results);
```

And then my action listener:

```
searchButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JsonReader reader = new JsonReader("assets/Rooms.txt");
            HotelRoom wanted = makeHotelRoomFromGuiInfo();
            String output = "";
            try {
                List<HotelRoom> allRooms = reader
                        .readHotelRoomObjectsFromFile();
                HotelRoomChooser chooser = new HotelRoomChooser(allRooms);
                List<HotelRoom> acceptable = chooser
                        .chooseRoomByPreferences(wanted);
                if (acceptable.size() == 0) {
                    output += "";
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < acceptable.size(); i++) {
                        output += String.valueOf(acceptable.get(i)
                                .getRoomNumber())
                                + String.valueOf(acceptable.get(i)
                                        .getListOfOccupiedDates()) + ",";
                    }

                }
                for (int i = 0; i < output.length();){
                    rooms[i] = output.split(",");
                    i++;
                }

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: _"so I'm having trouble with my action listener for my JTable."_ - What's the trouble?

Comment: To modify what a table contains, you must use the methods of the table's model. Modifying the array of rooms that has been used to construct the table won't work. Read the swing tutorial about JTable: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add after

```
for (int i = 0; i < output.length();){
   rooms[i] = output.split(",");
   i++;
}

results.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(rooms,columnNames )
```